# Amalgam of trees

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, trees, descriptive-set-theory

**Definition**  A tree is a partially ordered set $(T, <)$ such that for each $t \in T$, the set $\{s \in T : s < t\}$ is well-ordered by the relation $<$.

For trees $(T,<_T)$, $(S,<_S)$, $T\prec S$, if there is an embedding of $T$ into $S$, i.e. there exists an injection $f:T\rightarrow S$ such that for all $x,y\in T$, $x<_T y$ iff $f(x)<_S f(y)$.

Let $f_1,f_2$ witness that $T\prec S_1,S_2$ respectively. The "amalgam of $S_1,S_2$ over $T$" is a tree $R$ and embeddings $g_1,g_2$ such that $g_1,g_2$ witness that $S_1,S_2\prec R$ and $g_1\circ f_1=g_2\circ f_2$.

**Question** Does the amalgam always exist? Can we define it in many ways?

I was looking for a direct construction, i.e. defining $R$ from $T,S_1,S_2$, but I also found in Wikipedia the definition of a [push-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_%28category_theory%29). My background in category-theory is not strong enough. I could not tell if in the category of trees push-outs exists.

Any help either directly or through category-theory will be appreciated.

Comment: Amalgams definitely aren't unique by your definition: if $R$ is an amalgam, then so is any tree containing $R$.  Also, pushouts don't always exist in the category of trees, but I can't yet tell whether amalgams always exist...

Comment: If you restrict to finite rooted trees, you may realize them as a dense sub-category of planar operads (see for instance [this lecture](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783034800518-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1028946-p174058430) by I. Moerdijk). The category of planar operads is complete and cocomplete, so any pushout of (finite rooted) trees exists as a planar operad, though; i.e., as a certain "gluing" of trees.

Comment: @AndreaGagna. Thank you for the comment. Although not mentioned in the question, I am mainly interested in infinite trees. You can even assume that they are pruned trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An amalgam does not always exist.  Consider the poset $S=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ with the ordering $a<c$, $a<e$, $b<c$, and $b<d$.  Note that $S_1=S\setminus\{a\}$ and $S_2=S\setminus\{b\}$ are both trees with respect to this ordering.  Setting $T=S_1\cap S_2$, I claim that there does not exist any amalgam of $S_1$ and $S_2$ over $T$ (with $f_1$ and $f_2$ the inclusion maps).

Indeed, suppose we had such an amalgam $R$; let us abuse notation and treat $S_1$ and $S_2$ as subsets of $R$.  Then since $a,b<c$ we would have to have either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$ in $R$.  But if $a\leq b$, then we would have $a\leq b<d$ in $R$, which is impossible since $a\not<d$ in $S_2$.  Similarly, if $b\leq a$, we would have $b\leq a<e$ in $R$, which is impossible since $b\not<e$ in $S_1$.

Moreover, even when an amalgam does exist, and we require $R=g_1(S_1)\cup g_2(S_2)$ to avoid trivialities, the amalgam still will typically not be unique (up to isomorphism under $S_1$ and $S_2$).  For instance, consider $S_1=\{a\}$, $S_2=\{b\}$, and $T=\emptyset$.  Then there are four different minimal amalgams of $S_1$ and $S_2$ over $T$ (where "minimal" means $R=g_1(S_1)\cup g_2(S_2)$): one in which $a<b$, one in which $b<a$, one in which $a=b$, and one in which $a$ and $b$ are incomparable.

(For what it's worth, it's not hard to show that $R$ is a pushout of $S_1$ and $S_2$ over $T$ in the category of trees and embeddings iff $R$ is the unique minimal amalgam of $S_1$ and $S_2$.  So the question of whether there exists an essentially unique amalgam is indeed equivalent to asking whether there is a pushout in this category.)

Comment: Dear Eric Wofsey, I can not see they a,b have to be comparable in the amalgam $R$. In my mind, $S$ is an amalgam of $S_1,S_2$ over $T$.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos: In $R$, $a$ and $b$ are both elements of $\{r\in R:r<c\}$, which must be totally ordered.  Note that $S$ is just a poset, not a tree.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The definition I gave allows for "forests". This answers the question. I am wondering if there is a subclass of trees that admits amalgamation. E.g. if we require there is only one node of height zero. At least your example wouldn't work. But I am not sure if there is another example or not.

Comment: You can just embed my example in a single-rooted tree: add a new element $z$ to $S$ which is less than all the old elements, and then the same argument still works.  More generally, if $S_1'$ contains $S_1$, $S_2'$ contains $S_2$, and $T'$ contains $T$ (in a way compatible with the embeddings), then any amalgamation of $S_1'$ and $S_2'$ over $T'$ would have to contain an amalgamation of $S_1$ and $S_2$ over $T$.